# How to use Firebase push notification using custom data like image

Tags: android-studio

There is problem when sending the notification using firebase the notification in which the title and text is shown but when sending other data  the `String imgurl = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");` is on null reference how to solve this problem.

Here is my code

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
    String imgurl = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");


    bitmap = getbitmap(imgurl);


    getnotifiacation(bitmap, title, body, imgurl);
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {

}


private void getnotifiacation(Bitmap bitmap, String title, String body, String imgurl) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notifiaction = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setLargeIcon(getbitmap(imgurl))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, "notifiaction",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notifiaction.build());

}
   public static Bitmap getbitmap(String imgurl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imgurl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the error.The error was in  payload code here is the right code below

1 st

connect your app to firebase then after you have to implements the library for the firebase messaging service.

In Manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>
```

Create class FirebaseMessagingservice

public class FirebaseMessagingservice extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notifiaction;
Bitmap bitmap;
String id="Default";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{

    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
    String imgurl = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");

    //getting custom data from php

    bitmap=getbitmap(imgurl);



    getnotifiacation(bitmap,title,body,imgurl);
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {

}


private void getnotifiacation(Bitmap bitmap, String title, String body, String imgurl)
{

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notifiaction=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,id)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setLargeIcon(getbitmap(imgurl))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id,"notifiaction",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0,notifiaction.build());

}



public static Bitmap getbitmap(String imgurl)
{
    try
    {
        URL url=new URL(imgurl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        return  bitmap;

    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}// code for converting imgurl into bitmap
```

and here is the PHP code

[php code link](https://github.com/pranay289/Wroking_notification/blob/master/notifiaction_payload.php)

When app is background the onMessageReceived is not work for this above  payload code will work for you Thank you :)